# How to create one session file for both www and non-www

Tags: php, session

I would like to save my session to a pre-defined directory (actually outside of public_html). At the same time, I would like to create only one session file for both www and non-www for my site. For this purpose, I have placed the following code to the very beginning of my php page:

```
session_save_path('../path to outside of public_html directory/path to sessions directory');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1440);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".mysite.org");
session_start();
```

Although the session is being written successfully to that directory but it is creating separate session files to that directory for www and non-www inspite of using `ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".mysite.org");`.
Please note that my website's domain is `.org` and it is using `https://` and I don't want to use `.htaccess` for this purpose.

What would be the correct code? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense. Sessions are normally stored in cookies, for non-www requests there will be no cookies.

Comment: @bumperbox if you set `session_save_path('../include/sessions')`, at the very beginning of the php script, a session file (with a file name with that session id) will be created on the `sessions` directory for each visitor browsing your website. Now if the visitor type www.your-site.com or your-site.com in their web browsers, you will found that two separate files will be stored to that directory but eventually the visitor is same. What I want, no matter the visitor types with or without www., there will be only one session file with same session id in that directory. How to achieve that?